# MATLAB: set title of non-java command window

Tags: windows, matlab

### Question

How do you set the command window title for a MATLAB window launched without a desktop and without java?

- Matlab ver of primary interest:  2012a & later
- OS needed:  Windows (XP) primarily; something more general preferred
- Ideal solution: sets the title in the resulting window produced by the "mat" function described below.
- Alternate solution: set the command window title in the window produced by the "matj" function described below.

---

### Background

I have anonymous functions to launch "barebones MATLAB" windows (each executing from my main MATLAB window's terminal.

```
mat  = @(sCmd) system(['matlab.exe -nodesktop -nosplash -nojvm -r "' sCmd ';" &']);
matj = @(sCmd) system(['matlab.exe -nodesktop -nosplash -r "' sCmd ';" &']);
```

The "matj" window is more RAM-memory intensive than that produced by "mat".

I am aware of techniques to set the title in java-enabled windows, such as my following (which, curiously, did NOT work in the "matj" window):

```
cmdtitle = @(sT) com.mathworks.mde.desk.MLDesktop.getInstance.getClient('Command Window').getTopLevelAncestor.setTitle(sT)
```

---

### Why I need this/what I'm doing with this

I divvy memory-intensive non-plotting MATLAB tasks to these barebones-windows from a "master" MATLAB window (fully loaded with java & other bells/whistles).  Setting the title to these would allow me to give them a visual tag regarding that window's assigned task.

Also, it would be helpful to be able to expand the displayed-text buffer in these barebones windows (it seems they're limited to ~500 lines on my computer).  A work-around to the title-setting issue is to display a string to the terminal once the barebones window displays, but a limited buffer prevents that first line from persisting.

Suggestions on better/alternate ways to achieve these objectives are most appreciated, as is your time in reading/answering.  Thank you & good day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the sounds of it you are doing something akin to batch processing. You may want to look into the [Matlab Parallel Computing Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/parallel-computing/). The more recent versions of this & Matlab allow you to treat your computer as a mini compute-cluster and fire off batch jobs to it which could solve your problem neatly.

Alternatively, if you haven't got a license for that you could go the windows api route to setting the window title, and wrap that up in a mexFunction. Since it was interesting I have hacked together some code to do this:

```
//Include the windows api functions
#include <Windows.h>
//include the matlab mex function stuff
#include "mex.h"

DWORD processID; //the process id of the current matlab

//Callback function, this is the bit that sets the window text
BOOL CALLBACK SetTitleEnum( HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam ) {    
    DWORD dwID ;
    //get the process of the window this was called on
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &dwID); 
    //if it is our matlab instance, set the title text
    if(dwID == processID) SetWindowText(hwnd, (const char*) lParam);
    return true;
}

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[]) 
{
    //get the process id of this instance of matlab
    processID = GetCurrentProcessId(); 

    if (nrhs > 0) { //if we have been given a title
        char * title = mxArrayToString(prhs[0]); //get it as a char* string     
        //get all open windows and call the SetTitleEnum function on them
        EnumWindows((WNDENUMPROC)SetTitleEnum, (LPARAM) title);        
        mxFree(title);//free the title string.
    }
}
```

I compiled the above code in Matlab using Visual Studio 2010 Express and it worked fine for me, both in the restricted command line version and for the normal full desktop Matlab.

Comment: Thank you!  Your suggestion of an improved technique AND providing a method for my desired implementation is very much appreciated.  I just tested the MEX code, and it provides the desired functionality.